# react router v6 No routes matched location

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm want to navigate user to a specific url with a param into sees it as a list items with a view item button.
When I click the view button item  get the following warnng message

```
No routes matched location "/explore/0xD78Fb56DB0b68F9766975FEEbf7bFd0CF65C9F11"
```

in my App.js I have this

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Navbar />
        <Account />
      </Header>
      <div style={styles.content}>
        <Wrapper>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="create" element={<Creation user={account} />} />
            <Route path="/explore" element={<Explore />} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path='test' element={<Test />} />
          </Routes>
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

all this routes work fine
now in the /explore route I have my items list

and I did something like this (I followed the react-router doc)

```
return (
      <div style={{marginTop:'5em'}}>
        {isInitialized ?
        <div className='wrapper'>
          {eventArray.map(infoItem => (
            <div key={infoItem.id}>
            <CardEvent img={infoItem.pathImg ? infoItem.pathImg : lpass} 
            title={infoItem.idName} 
            date={infoItem.eventDate.toString()}
            />
            <Link to={`/explore/${infoItem.id}`}>View event </Link>
        </div>
        )
        )}
        <Routes>
        <Route 
        path='explore/:id'
        element={<Test />}
        />
      </Routes>
      </div> 
      : <p>Error</p>
      }
</div>
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You should give a param to your route
`<Route path='/dashboard/:string' element={<Dashboard />} />`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The route rendering the `Explore` component needs to specify a trailing wildcard matcher `"*"`, or splat, so descendent routes can also be matched.

[Descendent `<Routes>` with splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats)

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="create" element={<Creation user={account} />} />
  <Route
    path="/explore/*" // <-- add trailing wildcard matcher
    element={<Explore />}
  />
  <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path='test' element={<Test />} />
</Routes>
```

Keep in mind that `` <Link to={`/explore/${infoItem.id}`}>View event</Link> `` is specifying an absolute path `"/explore/:id"` and nested `Routes` components builds from the parent route:

```
<Link to={`/explore/${infoItem.id}`}>View event</Link>

...

<Routes>
  <Route 
    path='/:id' // <-- Omit "/explore" from path
    element={<Test />}
  />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-no-routes-matched-location]

Or to use relative routing, omit the leading `"/"` slash and link relatively to the `infoItem.id`.

```
<Link to={`${infoItem.id}`}>View event</Link>

...

<Routes>
  <Route path=':id' element={<Test />} />
</Routes>
```

### Update

> So is there anyway to render in a new page and not under my component?
> So if I go to `"/explore/event1"` `Test` does not appear under the event
> list but in another new blank page?

Yes. For this I suggest a small refactor to move the `<Route path=':id' element={<Test />} />` out to the main routing. Use a layout route to render an `Outlet` and nest an index route specifically for `Explore` and a nested route for `Test`. Remove the `Routes` code from `Explore`.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="create" element={<Creation user={account} />} />
  <Route path="/explore">
    <Route index element={<Explore />} />   // "/explore"
    <Route path=":id" element={<Test />} /> // "/explore/:id"
  </Route>
  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="test" element={<Test />} />
</Routes>
```

Explore

```
return (
  <div style={{marginTop:'5em'}}>
    {isInitialized ?
      <div className='wrapper'>
        {eventArray.map(infoItem => (
          <div key={infoItem.id}>
            <CardEvent
              img={infoItem.pathImg ? infoItem.pathImg : lpass} 
              title={infoItem.idName} 
              date={infoItem.eventDate.toString()}
            />
            <Link to={`/explore/${infoItem.id}`}>View event </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div> 
      : <p>Error</p>
    }
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-no-routes-matched-location (forked)]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, after using the relative routing I no longer have the warning that the route does not exist. But when I click it it does not display the test component.

Comment: @ElPandario Ok, let me standup a codesandbox to test this code out to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Actually my bad I just noticed it renders it correctly but it does not redirect me to a "white page".

Comment: @ElPandario Ok, I forgot that nesting a `Routes` component within a `Routes` component that is also still builds relative routes. It works when you omit the `"/explore"` from the nested route. I've updated and added a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-no-routes-matched-location-9mfwc3). Sorry for any confusion I may've caused.

Comment: Ok no worreis it's probably me that explained it wrong. So is there anyway to render in a new page and not under my component? So if I go to /explore/event1 test does not appear under tthe event list but in another new blank page?

Comment: @ElPandario Oh, I see, so you want `<Route path=':id' element={<Test />} />` out on its own page, sans everything in the `Explore` component?

Comment: yes exactly. I tried to create it's own route but Explore is in the url each time because I click the link from the explore page.

Comment: @ElPandario I've updated answer again and forked another [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-no-routes-matched-location-forked-pxe54t?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare your routes like this ?

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header style={styles.header}>
    <Navbar />
    <Account />
  </Header>
  <div style={styles.content}>
    <Wrapper>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="create" element={<Creation user={account} />} />
        <Route path="explore" element={<Explore />}>
          <Route path=":exploreId" element={<Test />} />   // Wrap this route inside the explore route
        </Route>
        <Route path='dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='test' element={<Test />} />
      </Routes>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: That's what I did first, I don't get error but nothing happens on the page so I thought I had to do something on my explore page.